# How to write content of a list of dict into a file in python

Tags: python

I am getting the output as a list of dict from a db call and I want to write the output into a file with some configuration. 
Example

```
my_dict = [{'pattern': "abc", 'message': "This is not possible"},
           {'pattern': "def", 'message': "The parameter provided application is invalid"},
           {'pattern': "ijk",'message': "Expected value for debugging"}
           ]
# want to write the op like below into some file.
# key's will be header also some case i need to ignore the headers.
pattern|message # file header
abc|This is not possible # file data
def|The parameter provided application is invalid # file data
ijk|Expected value for debugging # file data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('my.log', 'w') as log:
    log.write('pattern|message\n')
    for line in my_dict:
        log.write('{pattern}|{message}\n'.format(**line))
```

my.log

```
pattern|message
abc|This is not possible
def|The parameter provided application is invalid
ijk|Expected value for debugging
```

Comment: Thanks! My headers are based on the output from a table and it will be dynamic. How to make that? @xi

Comment: Instead of writing a literal string, write the variable that contains the headers...